# Is there a bluetooth phone that can remain paired with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

What I would like to do is find a bluetooth capable phone that I can pair with my iPhone and will remain paired even if my iPhone is paired with a bluetooth headset at the same time.

I had purchased the AT&T phone model TL92278, but, if I forgot to turn off my headset just before I returned home, the phone would no longer be paired with my iPhone. It was easy, but annoying to have to pair it again constantly.

Basically, I am wondering if there is a phone out there that can remain paired with my iPhone while my iPhone is paired with a headset.

Comment: paired and doing what?

Comment: Waiting for a phone call.

Comment: I still dont understand what a phone paired to an iPhone does for you.

Comment: I can have multiple handsets spread throughout my home and when someone calls me on my iPhone, those handsets will ring. I do not need to carry my iPhone with me all of the time while at home.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experience with Uniden. They make a range of phones that pair to your iPhone via bluetooth. They are good for incoming but have not yet worked out how to make outgoing calls through them.

Comment: And, if you arrive at home with your phone paired with a bluetooth headset, does your Uniden phone remain paired with your iPhone?